Compton scattering angle formula and drawings
The Compton formula for scattering angles $\varphi$ and $\theta$ for electron and photon, respectively, can be shown as:
$$ \cot\varphi = (1+\frac{\lambda_c}{\lambda_i})\tan\frac{\theta}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
where $\lambda_c = \frac{h}{m_e c}$ is the Compton wavelength of the electron which is equal to $2.43\times 10^{−12}$m.
Below is the spectrum of X-rays in question.



Xray $\lambda_i$ (nm)
0.5
0.1
0.02
0.01
0.005
0.0025




Photon $E_i$ (keV)
2.48
12.4
62.1
124
248
497


Ratio of ${\lambda_c}/{\lambda_i}$
0.0049
0.024
0.122
0.243
0.486
0.972



For ${\lambda_c}/{\lambda_i}\ll 1$, Equation \eqref{eq1} reduces to:
$$ \cot\varphi \approx \tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \cot(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2})\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$ Hence
$$ \varphi =  \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2} \tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
The plot of $\varphi$ against $\theta$ for Equation \eqref{eq3} is a straight line with a slope of $-\frac{1}{2}$ and intercept of $\frac{\pi}{2}$  as shown in Fig.4 subplot for the lower 3 energy X-rays in the above table. The higher 3 energy X-rays in the above table are plotted below.

As can be seen in the above subplot Fig.4, they approximate to the straight line even for ${\lambda_c}/{\lambda_i} \approx 1$.
When we scan $0 < \theta <180^{\circ}$ in sequence, $0 < \varphi<90^{\circ}$ is scanned in the opposite direction as illustrated below:

The customary Fig.2 of the picture showing $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in the 1st and fourth quadrant should never happen. Both $\theta$ and $\varphi$ are either in the same quadrant, 1 or 4 when they cross each other at $\pm 60^\circ$, or $\theta$ can go to 2 and 3, respectively. Would you agree?

What is it precisely that you are asking for?

As for the quadrants, you are misunderstanding. The angle $\varphi$ is measured positive as it descends into the 4th quadrant. i.e. when $\theta$ is a small positive value, i.e. in the 1st quadrant, then $\varphi$ is also "in the 1st quadrant", but in the way we have defined things, it appears in the 4th quadrant, as drawn in Figure 2 of the Wikipedia picture you linked to. i.e. The picture is correct.

For instance, #3 has both $\theta$ and $\varphi$ in 1st quadrant, #6 has $\theta$ in 2nd quadrant and $\varphi$ in 1st quadrant. They have to obey Eq.3, i.e. $\varphi + \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$. There is no instance when  $\theta$ is in 1st quadrant and $\varphi$ in 4th quadrant as Wiki showed. From the subplot Fig.4 above, for $\varphi$ in 4th quadrant, i.e. negative $\varphi$, $\theta$ has to be either in 3rd or 4th quadrant, i.e. in [180, 360].

No, you are misunderstanding it. Wiki is correct; what you think of as $\varphi$ is $\phi=-\varphi$; your 1st quadrant $\varphi$ is actually in the 4th quadrant $\phi$

But Wiki clearly defined $\varphi$ as "It can further be seen that the angle φ of the outgoing electron with the direction of the incoming photon is specified by (Eq.4)". I am confused by this new angle $\phi$ = $-\varphi$?

I am referring to your question on this site, which is in agreement with the convention on Wikipedia. By considering Equation (3) in your question there, it is very clear that as $\varphi$ increases a little bit from zero, it is going into 4th quadrant. You think it is in 1st quadrant. You are wrong on that.

As @naturallyInconsistent pointed out, I made a wrong interpretation of eq. (3). When the magnitude of $\pi/2>\varphi>0$, the scattered photon angle should be negated as $(-\pi/2, 0)$.
Another view is that, if we assume the photon was scattered into a positive angle $\beta$ direction, the conservation of momentum would yield:
\begin{align}
p_i &= p_f \cos \theta+p \cos \beta \ \ \ (x-\mathrm{component}) \tag{2''} \\
0 &= p_f \sin \theta + p \sin \beta \ \ \ (y-\mathrm{component})\tag{3''}
\end{align}
By substituting $\beta = -\varphi$ into eq. \eqref{eq2} and eq. \eqref{eq3}, they would reduce to eq. (2) and eq. (3), respectively. If we continued to carry out the $\beta$ versus $\theta$ derivation from eq. \eqref{eq2} and eq. \eqref{eq3} as before, we would arrive at:
$$ \cot\beta = -\left(1+\frac{h}{\lambda_i m_e c}\right)\tan\frac{\theta}{2}= -\left(1+\frac{\lambda_c}{\lambda_i}\right)\tan\frac{\theta}{2}.\tag{6$''$}\label{eq6}
$$
Again, by substituting $\beta = -\varphi$ into eq. \eqref{eq6}, we would have eq. (6). For ${\lambda_c}/{\lambda_i} \ll 1$, it reduces to
$$ \beta \approx -\left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right). \tag{3$'$}\label{eq3'}
$$
Therefore, the correct scanning drawing of angles $\beta$ vs $\theta$ would be:

The two angles $\beta$ and $\theta$ are split in different quadrants, and never cross each other.

Is this an answer or an update to the question?

This is an answer to correct my errors.
